# How can I share a link including a quote from a web page to Facebook post from the Facebook browser?

Tags: html, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-browser

I have created a web APP using Django that provides quizzes and created a Facebook App for it. When the user finishes the quiz he is asked to share his results to Facebook, when the user pressed the share button I create a Facebook post that includes my website page URL, a thumbnail, and a quote and besides that the Facebook App name also appears in its place in the post as well.
I am using the following in the HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
                    app_id=id
                    &quote={{quote}}
                    &href=http:link
                    &redirect_uri=link
                    "
               title="Share on Facebook">
                <span class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></span>
</a>
```

Everything is working fine in all browsers, but when I practice the quiz in the Facebook browser and press the share button, nothing is passed to the share box from things mentioned above and the share box appears empty!

I am new to this so can anyone help me to figure out where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook share UI that have provide this feature https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/

In my case I was doing:

```
 window.FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'url',
    hashtag: '#hashtag',
    quote: 'quote',
    display: 'popup'
  }, function (response) {
    if (response === undefined) {
      return
    }
    handleSuccess()
  })
```